# How do i run PMD on a command line in linux

Tags: pmd

I tried

```
$java -jar ../lib/pmd-5.0.0.jar /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MYPROJECT/workspace/ xml
```

error: 
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
../lib/pmd-5.0.0.jar

as per docs from [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/running.html)

i also tried:

```
$java -jar ../lib/pmd-5.0.0.jar /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MYPROJECT/workspace/ xml java-basic,java-design -encoding UTF-8
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
../lib/pmd-5.0.0.jar
```

resolved it by using the following Syntax:

```
cd ../pmd/bin
./run.sh pmd  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MYPROJECT/ xml java-basic,java-design -encoding UTF-8 | tee ../../MYPROJECT/pmd.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you see that in the [doc you linked to](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/running.html)?

All of the examples I see on that page say to run java using the PMD class name rather than with the -jar flag.  (Which is what I use when running PMD)

Which gives you something like:
    java net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MYPROJECT/workspace/ xml rulesets/java/imports.xml

Comment: when i use java -jar type command line i get:

 java -jar pmd-5.0.0.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MYPROJECT/ xml java-basic,java-design -encoding UTF-8
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
pmd-5.0.0.jar

Comment: What happened when you tried the java command (without the jar) as suggested on the documentation page?  My guess is that it will fail with a clearer error message about what is wrong.

Comment: got it working using:
./run.sh pmd  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MYPROJECT/ xml java-basic,java-design -encoding UTF-8